# How to assign additional properties to Excel worksheets, so that each sheet can share functionality, but use different settings?

Tags: excel, vba

Consider an excel workbook with 3 worksheets.

Each worksheet contains an draw button and a clear button.

The draw button colours a pre-determined selection of cells that form a square.

The clear button simply clears the worksheet.

Easily achieved, with something like this:

```
Private Sub Draw_Button_Clicked()
    Dim col As Colour
    Dim cells As Range
    
    col = <a colour>
    cells = <some cells> 

    Draw(colour, cells)
End Sub
```

Now, this is fine, but each worksheet colours different cells and uses a different colour. Suddenly, I find myself writing 3 copies of this same function and just changing the colur and the range.

Let us say that the project expands and 100 worksheets are needed. I COULD just copy and paste the same function over and over, but it seems silly. It is especially problmeatic when it is decided that the function should work slightly differently; at which point, each of the 100 functions must be changed indivisually.

Is there a way that I can tie the two variables to the worksheet itself and store the function somewhere else? I realise this is an over simplified case, so it may seem silly, but in practice the REAL function is large and continues to grow. I keep adding more settings and additional functionality.

Thankyou

Comment: You can add `Property`s to each sheet within the sheet code module?

Comment: If you put the code in the worksheets scope (in the VBA editor) instead of a module, it will copy the code too if you copy the worksheet. • Actually your question is not really clear. Can you give a concrete example? Mabye reading [mcve] helps too to improve the question.

Comment: I have rephrased the description. I was tired when I wrote it and clearly rushed too much. PLease let me know if you want anything clarifying.

Comment: The `Draw` and `Clear` being in a module. The `Click` event being in the sheet is the correct arrangement. No matter what you do, you will need to specify the settings unique to each sheet. If all the code is in the `Draw` and `Clear` then you only have to make changes in one place. If you have to change the settings on 1,000 sheets then yes, that is what you have to do.

Comment: Okay, then suppose each sheet has 1000 different draw function, which operate slightly differently, but all need to make use of those two variables. I would need to set the variables in each function

Comment: @OliverMorrison Just an idea but check if my answer helps to improve your issue. With this approach you only have one function `GetProperties` in each sheet to define its properties. All the code is in the class module and the one standard module for the button calls is needed. Should work, but there is probably room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best solution but it works:

**Create a class `MySheetClass`**

```
Option Explicit

'CLASS MODULE CODE: MySheetClass Class
Private m_Sheet As Worksheet
Private m_properties As Object

'set a reference to the worksheet you want to "wrap" with your class
Property Set Worksheet(Sheet As Worksheet)
    Set m_Sheet = Sheet
    Set m_properties = Worksheets(m_Sheet.Name).GetProperties
End Property

Property Get Worksheet() As Worksheet
    Set Worksheet = m_Sheet
End Property

Sub ColorizeTableRange()
    m_properties("TableRange").Interior.Color = m_properties("TableColor")
End Sub

'other methods/functions
```

**Create a standard module**

This is the procedure your sheet buttons get linked with. So all buttons on all sheets that should colorize a table are getting linked with this one procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColorizeButton_Click()
    Dim ws As New MySheetClass
    Set ws.Worksheet = ActiveSheet
    ws.ColorizeTableRange
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Now implement a `GetProperties` function in your `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetProperties() As Object
    Dim Dict As Object
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dict.Add "TableColor", vbRed
    Dict.Add "TableRange", Me.Range("A1:A10")
    
    Set GetProperties = Dict
End Function
```

**And another in your `Sheet2`**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetProperties() As Object
    Dim Dict As Object
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dict.Add "TableColor", vbGreen
    Dict.Add "TableRange", Me.Range("B1:B10")
    
    Set GetProperties = Dict
End Function
```

If you click the colorize button in `Sheet1` it will color `A1:A10` in red and if you click the button in `Sheet2` it will color `B1:B10` in green.

---

Somehow I had the feeling I should implement an interface in the worksheets to guarantee the existance of the `GetProperties` function, but I couldn't work it out and got some private/public issues here. Maybe someone has more experieneces here, would like to see that as an alternative answer if it is possible at all.

Comment: This is brilliant, although my only concern is that this class object "MySheetClass" seems to be recreated every time a button is clicked. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Actually only if you declare it as a global variable that you initialize at workbook open. You still would need to `Set ws.Worksheet = ActiveSheet` so it loads the poperties `GetProperties` of the current sheet. • Measure the time how long it takes to create that class. I think you can forget that. • I added a `Set ws = Nothing` which I forgot before.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble. It seems that I can't access the "GetProperties" Function outside of that script.

It keeps saying "Object Required"

Comment: Outside which script? Don't get it sorry.

Comment: GetProperties is defined inside a module.

If I try to use GetProperties outside of its module I get errors :/

Comment: @OliverMorrison `GetProperties` should be in a sheets code not in a module. And you should not deal with `GetProperties` at all you just use it in a procedure in your class module like shown in `ColorizeTableRange` where for example `m_properties("TableColor")` reads the property that was defined in the sheet.